# sed line matching with exclamation

Tags: sed

I am trying to understand this `sed` line matching part.  What does it do exactly.  The patters is supposed to match comment lines starting with `##` and attempt to remove the comment characterrs at the front of the line.

```
  pn_ere="^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|${cmt})[[:space:]]+"

  sed -E -n "
    /$beg_ere/ {
      :L1
      n
      /$end_ere/z
      /$pn_ere/!z
      s/// ; p
      tL1
    }
  "
```

Comment: Well, looking at this [sed.js.org example](https://sed.js.org/?snippet=nE4eeB), it doesn't seem to match your description.

Comment: When one uses regular expression, does `sed` match as substring in the read line or the full pattern.  I think that `awk` does the opposite, but do not know which one gets done.